# how does swagger2markup work in spring boots application?

Tags: swagger

I try to understand the swagger2markup in http://swagger2markup.github.io/swagger2markup/1.3.1/

```
URL remoteSwaggerFile = new 
URL("http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json");
Path outputDirectory = Paths.get("build/asciidoc");

Swagger2MarkupConverter.from(remoteSwaggerFile) 
.build() 
.toFolder(outputDirectory);

 <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.szc.thirdparty.nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>markdown_to_asciidoc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
        <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger2markup</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It doesn't work, and it shows an error below:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.netzwerg.paleo.ColumnIds$StringColumnId
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.component.ParameterTableComponent.apply(ParameterTableComponent.java:76) ~[swagger2markup-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.component.PathOperationComponent.buildParametersSection(PathOperationComponent.java:198) ~[swagger2markup-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.component.PathOperationComponent.apply(PathOperationComponent.java:100) ~[swagger2markup-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.document.PathsDocument.applyPathOperationComponent(PathsDocument.java:223) ~[swagger2markup-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.document.PathsDocument.buildOperation(PathsDocument.java:207) ~[swagger2markup-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.document.PathsDocument.lambda$buildsPathsSection$0(PathsDocument.java:119) ~[swagger2markup-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
```

Do anyone know how swaggermarkup works? Please help, thx!

Comment: Also, for build/asciidoc, do i need to create a directory in my project or it will generate by the swagger2markup?

Comment: i also use swaggeruibundle